# How to access Singleton in external AS3 SWF

Tags: actionscript-3, singleton, external

How can you access a singleton instance within a loaded swf from the loading swf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loading swf you can do :

`myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinitionByName("managerPackage::EventManager").getInstance()`

"managerPackage" must be replaced by the full package name of EventManager class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is the solution i looked for! 
getDefinitionByName should of course be just getDefinition, but it does the trick!